# Perl: Return anonymous array from a subroutine

Tags: perl

I'm trying to return an anonymous array from a subroutine, however, when dumping the returned variable I only see one value (I'm expecting two).

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $fruits_ref = generate_fruits();
print "Fruits: " . Dumper($fruits_ref) . "\n";

sub generate_fruits
{
    return ("Apple", "Orange");
}
```

This outputs:

```
Fruits: $VAR1 = 'Orange';
```

How do I get the subroutine to return that array ref?

Comment: You're not returning an array, you're returning a list. An array is `["Apple", "Orange"]`

Comment: Is it possible to return the entire list? How might I unpack the list?

Comment: `$fruits_ref = [ generate_fruits() ]`

Comment: List becomes its last element when you pass it to scalar context. To pass to list context, you could do `my @fruits = generate_fruits();` . But that is likely not what you need - you seem to need a reference. For that, just use square brackets. Oh, another alternative is `my $fruits_ref = [generate_fruits()];`

Comment: Thanks @arkadiy. If you post a answer I'd be happy to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning an array (or a reference to array), you're returning a list. A reference to anonymous array is `["Apple", "Orange"]`

List becomes its last element when you pass it to scalar context. To pass to list context, you could do

```
my @fruits = generate_fruits();
```

But that is likely not what you need - you seem to need a reference. For that, just use square brackets.

Oh, another alternative is

```
my $fruits_ref = [generate_fruits()];
```

Comment: Nit: `["Apple", "Orange"]` is _not_ an array; it's a reference to an anonymous array. An array would be `@array = ("Apple", "Orange")`.

Answer (score 8):

Anonymous arrays are constructed with square brackets.

```
return [ 'Apple', 'Orange' ]
```